# Pass post data to another url and get url response in post response

Tags: node.js

I am trying to pass some data to `/card` then filter it and send to a url and the final response of my /card need to be response send from the url.

```
app.post('/card', (req, res) => {

    var testData = req.body.orderId;
    if(testData!=null){ 
        var options = {     
        uri: 'https://localhost',
        headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {"longUrl": testData}
      };
      request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // res.json(testData);
          console.log(body.id) // Print the shortened url.
        }
      });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Node.js core module http to make an http request from within your Node application.
You can consult the official documentation and various options here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback